# Inserting a multidimensional array into another multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$stack = array(
    'name'           => 'some data',
    'caption'        => 'some data',
    'published'      => 'some data',
    'updated_at'     => 'some data',
    'updated_by'     => 'some data'
);

$data = array('album_id' => 'someID');
```

How do i insert the data array into the stack array?

update: i tried array_unshift but it inserted the $data array in a second dimension within the multi but i want it at the same level as the others.

also, one more question

if I have another array like data and i want to insert it into the 3rd position how would i do that?

Comment: These are one-dimensional arrays, not multi-dimensional arrays. They are also hashes, which do not contain numerically indexed keys, but rather named keys. So, you can't insert it into a specified position because they do not really have a position. You can use array_slice for that. array_merge is how you would combine them together into a single array. The first array you specify in array_merge is the base, and all other arrays passed to array_merge after that will be added to the end.  You need to assign the result of array_merge to a new variable. Look it up on php.net for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$stack = $stack + $data;
```

Or

```
$stack =array_merge($stack, $data);
```

If you want to add `$data` to the 3rd position in `$stack`

```
$chunks = array_chunk($stack, 2, true);
$stack  = array_shift($chunks);
$stack  += $data;
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) { $stack += $chunk; }
```

Comment: that gave me 6 for some reason. the value 6, i tried array_unshift instead and got 6. array_merge just showed the array.