# Inserting multidimensional array into another multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

To preface, part of what i am attempting to do is separate as much code-behind as possible from front end code (major php functions are not in the middle of html to make it more readable). What i am working on is an 'editor' style page for different 'codes' used on the site, so to get them ready to display on the page, I am creating an array to display them all, which appears as follows:

```
$CodeListing = array(
    array(
        'CodeType' => 1,
        'CodeDesc' => 'Product',
        'CodeShrt' => 'Prod',
        'ResultsView' => Array(),
    ),
    array(
        'CodeType' => 4,
        'CodeDesc' => 'Version',
        'CodeShrt' => 'Vers',
        'ResultsView' => Array(),
    ),
    array(
        'CodeType' => 5,
        'CodeDesc' => 'Applications',
        'CodeShrt' => 'Apps',
        'ResultsView' => Array(),
    ),
    array(
        'CodeType' => 7,
        'CodeDesc' => 'Resellers',
        'CodeShrt' => 'Resell',
        'ResultsView' => Array(),
    ),
    array(
        'CodeType' => 8,
        'CodeDesc' => 'Roles',
        'CodeShrt' => 'Roles',
        'ResultsView' => Array(),
    )
);
```

All these codes are stored in a single MySQL table, and are uniquely identified by a Primary Key consisting of the CodeType & CodeValue columns. What i am attempting to do is fill in the value of each ResultsView with the associated data from the MySQL table using a foreach loop.

So i have taken a look at a couple of other questions here on Stack:
[Inserting a multidimensional array into another multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116562/inserting-a-multidimensional-array-into-another-multidimensional-array)

[Insert array into multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538140/insert-array-into-multidimensional-array)

I have tried using array_push and array_merge as suggested in them, but neither of those methods worked. when I do a `print_r` outside the foreach, or run a foreach on the ResultsView on the html side, it returns nothing (basically looks like above without anything defined for a value for any ResultsView keys.)

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
//Go through each CodeListing and set its ResultView to contain all code entries.
foreach ($CodeListing as $type) {
    //Generate the query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM code WHERE CodeType = '".$type['CodeType']."'";
    //Define order based on CodeType.
    //Certain CodeTypes require a unique sorting.
    if (in_array($type['CodeType'], array('1','6','7','8'))) {
        $query .= " ORDER BY CodeName;";
    } else {
        $query .= " ORDER BY CodeField1, CodeValue;";
    }
    //Get the results of query
    $result = $db -> select($query);
    //set the value of ResultsView.
    $type['ResultsView'] = $result;
}
/*
Query results from $db -> select($query) come back in the following format:
[0] => array(
   'CodeType' => SomeValue,
   'CodeValue' => SomeValue,
   'CodeName' => SomeValue,
   'CodeField1' => SomeValue,
   'CodeField2' => SomeValue,
)
[1] => array(
   'CodeType' => SomeValue,
   'CodeValue' => SomeValue1,
   'CodeName' => SomeValue1,
   'CodeField1' => SomeValue1,
   'CodeField2' => SomeValue1, 
)
...
etc.
*/
```

Like mentioned above, I am attempting to input the MySQL query results array into the value of a key in a multidimensional array, without any luck. Also, in its current state, my code throws no errors either.

If i check the value of the ResultsView key inside the foreach loop where I set the value, the array shows up when I do a `print_r` (also telling me that it is reaching the foreach loop in my code). outside that loop, my code acts like I never assigned a value at all to any of the ResultsView keys, and I don't understand why, or what I am missing so the value stays assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not addressing where to put results correctly. The `$type` only exists within your loop, it's meant for *reading from* the array not for *writing to*.

You need to include the array key in your loop and use it to assign result to the correct location in the original array:

```php
foreach ($CodeListing as $key => $type) {

    // ...

    $CodeListing[$key]['ResultsView'] = $result;
}
```